# Deserialize Json error

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I have the following code:

```
public string BulkAttendaceSave(string userName, string password, string Json)
{
    DataSet ds = (DataSet)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json, (typeof(DataSet)));
}
```

the JSon that I am passing is:

```
[{"staff_id":"12","site_code":"S2","att_date":"1-7-2013","work_hour":"1.00"}]
```

I am getting error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.
>      at attendence.BulkAttendaceSave(String userName, String password, String Json)

What is the problem with the code? Please help out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json string is not in valid format to be parsed as DataSet. It should be object with tables inside. Each table should contain array of rows:

```
{ 
   "Table1": [
     {"staff_id":"12","site_code":"S2","att_date":"1-7-2013","work_hour":"1.00"}
   ]
}
```

Now it can be deserialized as `DataSet`. Your current json string can be deserialized to `DataTable`:

```
var dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(DataTable));
```

Result:

[image]